# Cannot Get / when running angular app

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core

I have an Angular 5 app that was running just fine. I made some changes while it was running, and everything refreshed fine. Then I stopped the debugger and checked it in to source control.

Now when I run it, I get "Cannot Get /". But if I "fake" change a TS file just so I can save and refresh the page, it'll usually run, or sometimes give me the "loading" page but go no further. No console errors, nothing to indicate what the issue is. Seems that when I "change" a TS file and save and refresh, a "script documents" folder is created (in solution explorer) with all the JS files. I believe I remember seeing this getting created on startup normally, which it doesn't seem to be doing now. But not sure why.

I've had the issue before, but it was always due to an error in a TS file that I hadn't noticed. This time, I've checked my source control history and gone through every file for errors or anything that could possibly cause an issue, and found nothing. I've made no major changes since it was working, and I've even rebooted thinking that VS had just lost its mind.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, while I was changing some typescript stuff while things were running, I had added a setTimeout to my code. This apparently added the line:

```
import { setTimeout } from 'timers';
```

to the TS file, and things continued to run fine from what I could tell. But apparently that line isn't needed (and clearly wrong for whatever reason), and that was completely preventing the TS from being compiled, even though it wasn't showing that it didn't like it.

Comment: You should consider deleting your original question.

Comment: Why would I do that?  Someone else might some day have the same issue and it could help them. As a beginner, I never would have thought an import statement could cause such a problem, especially one that was automatically added for me when adding that code.